# array allow values

Tags: php, arrays

```
if ( in_array( $plink, array( '404', 'sitemap' ) ) ) continue;
```

I need to invert condition i.e. allowed these values '404', 'sitemap' in loop. Don't exclude / only allow...

Answer (score 3):

For inverting/negation condition use `!`.

```
if ( !in_array( $plink, array( '404', 'sitemap' ) ) ) continue;
```

It's the same principle like you probably know `$a != $b`.

Answer (score 1):

use NOT operator to get negation of the condition. See the code below.

```
if ( !in_array( $plink, array( '404', 'sitemap' ) ) ) {
    echo "do what you want";
}
```

Comment: thx... but If I remove 'continue' statement this does not work as an 'inversion', from the solution above